# NGINX to serve angular and react bundle files upon location URL?

Tags: angular, reactjs, nginx

I am moving my project from angular to React for multiple reasons. But upon the time constraints, I decided to move only one module at a time, either serving new modules in React and serving old one with Angular Assets. What would be the best practice to achieve this?

I heard NGINX could solve the issue by serving Angular or React asset upon requested URL.

example:
/v1/url1 would give me the Angular asset

/v2/url2 would give me React Asset

Comment: Yes, you can use Nginx as a proxy server if you are doing server rendering.

Comment: There is no best practice because what you want to achieve is not recommendable. But NGINX will get you there.

Comment: @Carsten Thanks, But what would be the recommended way?